# how to set the option "system.defaults.dock.autohide" for multi users using nix-darwin?

Tags: macos, nix

I installed nix in multi-user mode and nix-darwin.

I'm able to set `"system.defaults.dock.autohide" to true`, this effects preferences of the user from which darwin-rebuild command is run. Is it possible to specify this option for other users ?

Comment: This may be a nix-darwin implementation error.

Comment: @RobertHensing, didn't get you, what might be a nix-darwin implementation error?

Comment: The option doesn't say that it only applies to the current user, so the current behavior seems wrong. Is it possible to set it for all users with a shell command?

Comment: It's probably best to create a pr or issue for nix-darwin. I don't think you'll reach many nix-darwin users, let alone devs through here. There's not even a nix-darwin tag.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Not sure if it is possible to set it for all users using shell command. 
yeah makes sense, will raise the issue on nix-darwin repo.